# magento2: how to get value of custom attribute

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute

I created "unit of mass" attribute for product in admin.I want to show it in final_price.phtml page .how to call there

Comment: @Rakesh : attribute code - unit of mass

Comment: use $block->getSaleableItem()->getUnitOfMass(); in your page and check

Comment: @Rakesh its not working

Comment: no unit of mass, no underscores

Comment: I am just telling about code not lable. please check inside Product Attribute -> Advanced Attribute Properties -> Attribute code in backend.

Comment: In attribute code of product, Please use only letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) or underscore (_) in this field, and the first character should be a letter.

Comment: ok i will check it update you

Comment: If you want to display attribute code in listing page, you have to set attribute value Used IN Product listing page Yes  from attribute page from backend.

Comment: @Rakesh  its not coming

Comment: Did you try $product->getCustomAttribute($attributeCode)?

Comment: @klict  $product?

Comment: @Nadh $block->getSaleableItem()->getCustomAttribute($attributeCode)